# использовать часть url как get-параметр

Tags: nginx

есть такое перенаправление для захода на главную страницу, которое осуществляется *nginx*-ом:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

как можно сделать такое же перенаправление, но чтобы на `index.php` выполнялся get-запрос с параметром, наподобие:

```
location /user/число {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?user=число;
}
```

Comment: А что такое реврайт? Вы либо пользуетесь оригинальными терминами на латинице, либо по-русски, если есть прямые аналоги.

Comment: @0xdb перенаправление

Comment: @Alex78191 - ну я то примерно понял о чём речь,  rewrite можно и переписать перевести, потому и предложил правку.

Answer (score 1):

части *url* можно группировать с помощью скобок, а внутри блока обращаться к группам по номерам: `$1` — первая группа, `$2` — вторая, и т.д.

например, так:

```
location ~ /user/(\d+) {
  try_files ... /index.php?user=$1;
}
```

---

кстати, группам можно [присваиваить имена](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) с помощью конструкции `?<имя>`:

```
location ~ /user/(?<nomer>\d+) {
  try_files ... /index.php?user=$nomer;
}
```